# Can I always write the 艹 (grass radical) with three lines only?

Tags: characters, writing, radicals, handwriting

The 艹 (grass radical) is present in for example 歡　and 貓 and 喵

In some fonts it's rendered as two separate crosses 十十， in some as one horizontal line with two vertical lines crossing it.

**Can I always write the grass radical in either way, or are there certain characters/situations that demand either way of writing it to be correct?**

Comment: in formal writing, you should separate the two crosses, in casual hand written note, you can simplify it with three stokes

Comment: @TangHo, This could be regional, in mainland, some teachers would take it wrong.

Comment: 3 strokes, see online dictionaries, e.g. http://bishun.shufaji.com/0x8336.html that draw each character stroke by stroke,

Comment: If you want to write it rightly, you must write two 屮-s, that is 艸.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two notes:

- **艹** is 4 strokes in Taiwan and Hong Kong **only**. It is less helpful to think of it as a "traditional"/"simplified" difference, as among other standards which use "traditional characters" (e.g. Korean Hanja), it is also 3 strokes.
- **歡** *does not* strictly contain 艹; it is historically written with **卝**, commonly known as **羊頭**. In modern times, the distinction may be relaxed, and many fonts may display it with 艹. Please refer to [this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-meaning-significance-of-the-%E5%8D%9D-component-in-traditional-Chinese-characters-as-in-%E8%8C%8D-distinct-from-the-%E8%89%B9-in-%E8%8B%9F/answers/59717808?srid=Qog4) Quora answer detailing what kinds of characters contain 卝 rather than 艹.

To "write things correctly", you need to understand what kind of regional Han character standard you're adhering to and look up the character in their official list. Otherwise, you should stick to the most recent common ancestor of all Han character standards, which is the Kangxi Dictionary standard.

Answer (score 2):

Writing two crosses is the "canonical" type, which adheres to the origin of the radical. When you're in Taiwan or Hong Kong, this is the best choice.
Writing it together as a laid-down two-barred cross is the only accepted writing in Simplified Chinese.

Answer (score 1):

Rendering it as two separate crosses 十十 is kind of traditional writing. In modern writing, we write one horizontal line with two vertical lines crossing it. Some would write traditionally in the calligraphy.

Answer (score 1):

The link given by @user6065 :http://bishun.shufaji.com/0x8279.html   classifies the two small strokes as 丨shù .
These two strokes are very small and look more like small vertical dots 丶 diǎn.
Then what is correct ? i would say the second...